# Close session connection in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, session, hibernate-criteria

This is my Hibernate criteria query:

```java
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(myclass.class, "b");
ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
listArr = criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(HashMap.class)).list();
```

I want to close session connection after executing query.

Comment: if you want to close the session, you will most likely not to any more database access and therefore you can simply close the sessionFactory

Comment: I have tried sessionFactory.close() but still connection remains in idle state.

Comment: try `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().disconnect();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close();
sessionFactory.close();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried these but still connection not close. Connection will close after some time interval.

Answer (score 2):

You are use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(), So you no need to flush and close session. it automatically flush and close when transaction end.

**more**

**getCurrentSession**

When you call SessionFactory. getCurrentSession, it will provide you session object which is in hibernate context and managed by hibernate internally. It is bound to transaction scope.
When you call SessionFactory. getCurrentSession , it creates a new Session if not exists , else use same session which is in current hibernate context.

**openSession**

When you call SessionFactory.openSession, it always create new Session object afresh and give it to you. You need to explicitly flush and close these session objects. As session objects are not thread safe, you need to create one session object per request in multithreaded environment and one session per request in web applications too.

If you are using hibernate in single threaded environment , you can use getCurrentSession